# One-to-one plus many-to-many relationships with the same object not building correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I'm using the Entity Framework 4 code first approach to design my database in ASP MVC 3 and I ran into a bit of a hitch. I have a POCO class as below:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public Session ActiveSession { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Session> InSessions { get; set; }
}
```

with `Session` as another one of my model classes defined elsewhere, with `ICollection<User>` as one of its properties. If I remove the `public Session ActiveSession { get; set; }` property from the `User` class, then the many-to-many mapping and `UserSessions` intermediate table are constructed correctly, but when I add the `ActiveSession` one-to-one mapping back in, it breaks the many-to-many mapping and the intermediate table is not constructed. Instead the `Users` table has a single foreign key to the `Sessions` table each for both the `ActiveSession` and `InSessions` properties. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: can you show your mapping code?

Comment: @Eranga The above is pretty much it. I'm using the code first approach so I don't have an edmx model, and so far I haven't needed to use any of the mapping fluent API or attributes. EF is building my database for me, so I don't have to map to any existing tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case EF thinks that `ICollection<User>` in `Session` class is the `Many` end of the one to many relationship created by `ActiveSession`.

So you need to configure mannualy

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.ActiveSession)
   .WithMany()
   .Map(u => u.MapKey("ForeignKeyColumn"));

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
   .HasMany(u => u.InSessions)
   .WithMany(s => s.Users)
   .Map(m =>
       {
           m.ToTable("UserSessions");
           m.MapLeftKey("UserID");
           m.MapRightKey("SessionID");
       });
```